# Is it possible to draw WPF DataGrid row separators without actual data?

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, datagridview, wpfdatagrid

I have requirement to draw totaly same user controls like designer told me.

One of DataGrids contains row separators without actuall data:

[image]

Is it possible to draw separators to the end of the DataGrid without adding fake data? 
(I don't want scrollbar appear and also those rows should be not selectable)

Comment: answer was found on a proposed "duplicate" page. So question can be closed.